# Populate struct with variables

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I have this struct (in a separate swift file):

```
struct Section {
    var infoType: String!
    var info: [String]!
    var icon: [UIImage]!
    var expanded: Bool!

    init(infoType: String, info: [String],icon: [UIImage], expanded: Bool) {
        self.infoType = genre
        self.info = movies
        self.icon = icon
        self.expanded = expanded
    }

}
```

I use it to populate a `tableView`
In the `viewController I do this:

```
class UserInTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   private var userName: String = ""


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var sections = [
        Section(infoType: "Venue Info": ,
                info: [], //I want to populate this array with string variables
                icon: [],
                expanded: false),
        Section(infoType: "User Info": ,
                info: [], //I want to populate this array with string variables    
                icon: [],    
                expanded: false),
        Section(infoType: "Other Info": ,
                info: [], //I want to populate this array with string variables
                icon: [],
                expanded: false)

    ]
```

How can I populate this with variables?

Comment: Where would the strings come from? If you already have them in variables, simply put the variables in the array, otherwise put the string literals in the array. Or pass the array into the initialiser. Btw no variables in `Section` should be implicitly unwrapped optionals, simply declare them as non-Optionals. Moreover, there's no need for the initialiser, the compiler will create a member wise initialiser matching the one you wrote.

Comment: What do  you mean by **with variables**?

Comment: Unrelated but you get the initializer in `Section` for free. You can delete it. And **never ever** declare properties/members as IUO which are initialized with non-optional values. **Remove the exclamation marks**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by enumerating through your array

First, as per suggestions by Vadian, change it to non-optional and don't save the images directly to array, instead, save the name of the images.

```
struct Section {
    var infoType: String
    var info: [String]
    var icon: [UIImage]
    var expanded: Bool
}
```

Create a function in your viewController, what will change the contents to actual, whenever you will have it.

```
 func populateArrayWithActualInfo() {
     for (index,section) in self.sections.enumerated() {
            var secInside = section
            secInside.info = ["a", "b", "c"]
            self.sections[index] = secInside
     }
     print(self.sections)
 }
```

OR If you want to set the dynamic info from your already existing array then you can pass the same to the function.

```
func populateArrayWithActualInfo(_ yourData:[[String]]) {
         for (index,section) in self.sections.enumerated() {
                var secInside = section
                secInside.info = yourData[index]
                self.sections[index] = secInside
         }
         print(self.sections)
     }
```

Try it and share the results.

Comment: No, please! *Change it to **non**-optional*. Optionals are nonsense if the default value aren't `nil`. I edited the answer as you are mentioning *my suggestions*.

Comment: Also if you are going to mutate the data, consider using reference types (class) over structs.

Comment: @Desdenova that's true, class uses pass by reference mechanism, while struct is pass by value. Here I just took the code as a reference from the question so, used the same. Thanks for your information.